# Want to get the value based on the range of searching values

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am using Excel,

I have a excel sheet with the following data:

```
role    referrers
--------------
Role01  ref01
Role01  ref02
Role01  ref03
Role02  ref04
Role02  ref05
Role02  ref02
Role03  ref06
Role03  ref01
Role03  ref02
```

I have some input value, so how

```
Referrers Roles
---------------
ref02      ? 
ref01      ?
ref06      ?
```

How to find the output i.e Roles ?
I have used vLookup, used Referrers for searching the roles.
But not able to get any output.

The output should be:

```
   Referrers   Roles
  ---------------
   ref02       Role03
   ref01       Role03
   ref06       Role03
```

Comment: Why `ref02  -> Role03` According to the data you have posted, `ref02` is related to `Role03` and also `Role01`and also `Role02`. Have you tried using Pivot Tables?

Comment: Since the same ref02 is linked to all roles... I guess the Pivot Table is the answer.. How do you otherwise distinguish if you want to return Role01 or 02 or 03 for the given ref02?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns : Why `ref02 -> Role03` , I want to use `ref02, ref01 and ref06` and search, if with these 3 values any roles exists, then it should return `-> Role03`

Comment: @Wizhi : Do you have any such link where can i find how to search this data using `pivot` table ?

Comment: There is no logic behind this process. We need you to explain why `ref02` returns `Role03` instead of any other value. Please, explain the steps behind this process.